# Change an Eclipse key binding to work anywhere in the program

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 and one of the key bindings I changed that when pressed, only works when the File browser is focused. How can I get it to work no matter where I am in the program when I press the key binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the "When" attribute for the key binding to "In Windows".

Comment: It was already set `In Windows`. That makes it only work in the File Browser in the project. :(

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do it, so I will just accept the answer.